# Is there a wildcard for multiple characters in a string that I can pass to the .replace function?

Tags: python, string, replace, substring, wildcard

I am reading certain values from a json file and writing that data to a new file. The endgoal is translating .json to .yml files (there are over 350k files, so i cant just drop it in an online translator).

While doing this, I'm removing '<'tags'>' from the data. I have been using the .replace function to write the new strings without the undesired substrings.

Since i'm only interested in removing strings that start with '<' and end with '>', I was wondering if there was a wildcard character such as * or . that would work within the .replace function.

Here is my code:

```
with open('example' + '.txt') as json_data:
data=json.load(json_data)
for r in data['posts']:
    fo = open(str(r['no'])+".txt","w")
    resp = "--" + r['com']
    resp=resp.replace("<br>","")
    resp=resp.replace('<span class="quote">&gt;','')
    resp=resp.replace('</span>','')
    resp=resp.replace('<span>','')
    fo.write(resp)
    fo.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potential solution:

```
import re
re.sub('(<\S[^<]*>)', '', text)

#Examples
text1 = '</span> something <span>'
re.sub('(<\S[^<]*>)', '', text1)
#' something '

text2 = '<span class="quote">'
re.sub('(<\S[^<]*>)', '', text2)
#''
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow.

You can use regular expression, implemented in python in the `re` module.

```py
import re
regexp = re.compile(r"<.*>")
regexp.sub("", text)
```

Replaces everything between <> with an empty string.

Comment: Gentle suggestion: Please add a "." in `regexp = re.compile(r"<*>")` to make it 
`import re regexp = re.compile(r"<.*>") regexp.sub("", text) `